# Editing an application contains cloud messaging developed with c2dm will make any issue with cloud messaging?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-c2dm

I have an application in play store, which contains C2DM. Now i need to release an upgrade version of this app, will it affect the cloud messaging? I came to know that we should use GCM since C2DM is deprecated from june 2012. The new version only needs to update some sort of designs in the app, there wont be any edit in C2DM classes. So can i work with this app without migrating to GCM libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, C2DM still works and upgrading your app shouldn't affect it, though you are encouraged to [migrate to GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html).

> Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) is deprecated. The C2DM service will continue to be maintained in the short term, but C2DM will accept no new users, and it will grant no new quotas. C2DM developers are strongly encouraged to move to Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). GCM is the next generation of C2DM.